# how to clear event handles in c#

Tags: c#, event-handling

I'm using global variable named "client"

For example

```
client.getPagesCompleted += (s, ee) =>
{
    pages = ee.Result;
    BuildPages(tvPages.Items, 0);
    wait.Close();
};
client.getPagesAsync(cat.MainCategoryID);
```

I need to clear handlers for `getPagesCompleted` and set another handler. 
How to easy clear handles?
I know `client.getPagesCompleted-=new EventHandler(...)`. But it is very difficult. I need easy way.
I'm using `client.getPagesCompleted=null` but error shown. `"only use += / -+"`

Answer (score 6):

The only way to remove an event handler is to use the `-=` construct with the same handler as you added via `+=`.

If you need to add and remove the handler then you need to code it in a named method rather using an anonymous method/delegate.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to put your event handler in a separate method; you can still use your lambda function, but you need to assign it to a delegate variable. Something like:

```
MyEventHandler handler = (s, ee) => 
{ 
    pages = ee.Result; 
    BuildPages(tvPages.Items, 0); 
    wait.Close(); 
}; 

client.getPagesCompleted += handler; // Add event handler
// ...
client.getPagesCompleted -= handler; // Remove event handler
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the event object to a variable, and use `-=` to unsubscribe.